# I want to pass data from the URI to the Sign Up controller when submitting the Sign up form

Tags: php, laravel

My route to load the sign up page is

```
Route::get('join/{mobileNumber}', 'JoinController@index');
```

Is there any way to pass the variable 'mobileNumber' when submitting the form ?
I can create a hidden input in the form, but would it be the best way to further pass on the variable ?

Comment: If the value is filled in a form, you should use POST method on the form.

Comment: The problem is, I need to pass the variable 'mobileNumber' further after filling up the form and this variable is not a part of the form.

Comment: Then you should use a session. I'm not sure if laravel has this feature, but some PHP frameworks provides a flash session, which lifetime is due the next request. You can make it longer by "touching" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, passing the variable from the index method to the view:

#### routes.php

```
Route::get('join/{mobileNumber}', 'JoinController@getJoin');
Route::post('join/{mobileNumber}', 'JoinController@postJoin');
```

#### JoinController

```
<?php

# ...

    public function getJoin($mobileNumber)
    {
        # ...
        return view('mobile_join', compact('mobileNumber'));
    }

    public function postJoin($mobileNumber, RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $username = $request->input('username');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->phone = $mobilePhone;
        $user->is_active = 0;
        $user->save();

        # or

        $data = $request->only(['username', 'email']);
        $data['phone'] = $mobilePhone;
        $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
        $data['is_active'] = 0;

        $user = User::create($data);

        # ...

        redirect()->route('...');
    }
```

#### User.php - Model

```
protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password', 'is_active'];
```

#### mobile_join.blade.php

```
<form action="/join/{{ $mobileNumber }}" method="post">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

HTTP 1.1 supports two methods, GET and POST, and we are sending the form data through the POST and passing the mobileNumber through the GET. Laravel uses regular expression to extract the string from the URL and set the variable.

Comment: I have a RegisterRequest variable in the postJoin function in my JoinController:

`public function postJoin(RegisterRequest $request)`
 and 
`public function postJoin($mobileNumber, RegisterRequest $request)` is not working.

Comment: if you type `dd($mobileNumber);` in postJoin method, what happens?

Comment: The mobileNumber variable is displayed.

Comment: Okay, Now I have to add extra variables to a request object. Trying to search it. It'll be done most probably.

Comment: Do you want validate the mobileNumber in RegiterRequest?

Comment: No, the validation has been done before loading the signUp form. I just need to insert certain default values in the database which can be done in other ways too. I am trying to add this statement `$request['isActive']='0';` but it doesn't seem to work. I am surprised the statement `$request['password']=Hash::make($request['password']);` works but the former doesn't.

Comment: What's you database table name and Model? Are you using Eloquent?

Comment: Table name: "users"

Yes, I am using Eloquent.

Comment: Okay. It's done. Inserted the database fields in the protected $fillable variable in the model.

And changed the Request object $request  using `$dat['isActive']="0";
        $dat['balance']="0";
        $dat['level']="0";
        $dat['referrer']=$mobileNumber;`

Can now insert values in the db.